# What is the valuation of Snapshot process in Raft Consensus of Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, consensus, raft

I'm digging into the new consensus of Hyperledger Fabric 1.4. The concept of Raft and the way it works is quite clear in [the document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/orderer/ordering_service.html#raft).

But there is a concept called `snapshot`, which is

> While it’s possible to keep all logs indefinitely, in order to save disk space, Raft uses a process called “snapshotting”

I've read through the documents about Raft too (Ex: [this one](http://blog.carlosgaldino.com/a-brief-overview-of-the-raft-algorithm.html)), and understand the reason Raft need `snapshot` where it let the leaders and followers store less data (just snapshot and some new logs). But in the case of Fabric, the example about `snapshot` describe the way a lagging orderer get the missed blocks

> For example, let’s say lagging replica R1 was just reconnected to the network. Its latest block is 100. Leader L is at block 196, and is configured to snapshot at amount of data that in this case represents 20 blocks. R1 would therefore receive block 180 from L and then make a Deliver request for blocks 101 to 180. Blocks 180 to 196 would then be replicated to R1 through the normal Raft protocol

It confuses to me while the orderers store the full ledger, so why it still needs `snapshot` and how can it save disk space here?